# Implementing pub-sub on AWS

Tags: amazon-web-services, azure, publish-subscribe, servicebus

I am hoping I can get help with this.
I want a way to do this simple thing (which is possible with Azure Service Bus) but with *some native service* on AWS instead

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-bus-messaging/service-bus-dotnet-how-to-use-topics-subscriptions?tabs=passwordless

*In this quickstart, you'll do the following steps:

1. Create a Service Bus namespace, using the Azure portal.
2. Create a Service Bus topic, using the Azure portal.
3. Create a Service Bus subscription to that topic, using the Azure portal.
4. Write a .NET console application to send a set of messages to the topic.
5. Write a .NET console application to receive those messages from the subscription.*

Here, on #5, I am able to spin up a simple dotnet console application to receive messages from the azure service bus.Of course, the console app needs to be running and that is okay.

However, when I looked around and read up on options on AWS, I found SNS, EventBridge, Masstransit (which seems to abstract other tech underneath) and a few more - none seem to be able to let me do #5 above. All of them want an Http endpoint as the target for delivering their message. With the Azure Service Bus example above, it is a breeze to spin up a console app, register it as a listener and receive a message from the azure service bus subscription.

I did look at MSK and I do not know if it can solve what I need. But, from the initial impression, that will be an overkill for what I need. I do not streams. Just a couple hundred messages a week but the number of consumers could be many.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correct, you want to implement step 1 to 5 completely in AWS.

This is what I'd suggest you:

1. Use the default EventBus or create a new one on Eventbridge
2. Create a Lambda (you can write them in C# if that's necessary for you) that will publish to the topic of the eventbus and add your business logic into the handler
3. Create an Endpoint that triggers this lambda with Api Gateway (REST or Websocket possible if GrahQL is nedded use AppSync)
4. Create a second Lambda that gets triggered by the event (subscriber) and add your business logic into the handler

You can see the logs of the subscribed lambda in CloudWatchLogs. If you need an endpoint for the logs follow step 3 again but use the lambda as trigger for the endpoint.

All the services will need the right policies the AWS documentation will help you there.

I hope this helps you for further steps.

Comment: I'll also suggest about using CDK for it. This makes is easy for a reuse or adjustments

Comment: Thank you for your response. Yes, I read about Lambdas. But, it essentially boils down to having some Http endpoint as the target.  Let us say I have a dozen legacy asp.net apps running. Each already have some kind of background task implemented in them. I simply want to write some additional code which "can register itself"and start listening and get the messages delivered without having to create a new API in my asp.net apps and exposing them ass the targets for the messages to be delivered.  Today, I can do this easily with Azure Service bus topics and subscriptions.

Comment: With AWS, I am having a hard time but I am pretty sure it is just me not able to figure out a solution which many out there must have already implemented :)